# How to run asynchronous methods inside my ActionResult in MVC, c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, model-view-controller, async-await

I'm getting data from a web service.it took bit time. this is my `controller`

```
 {

         // THERE SO MANY FUNCTIONS BEFORE THIS.
         //   

            try
            {
                string serviceUrl = "https://www.myserviceweb.com/assets/webhandler/details.ashx";
                HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
                HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream());
                string result = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();


                var rootResult = XElement.Parse(result);

                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["rootvss"] = rootResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("error");
            }

  return View();
 }
```

before I call to this function, there are lot functions. so altogether it took more time to load the index.what I want to do is

**To run only above function asynchronously. how can I do that. I tried to use method like following.but I do not know how to use it.**

```
 public async Task webservce()
        {

        }
```

hope your help with this

Comment: `async` isn't some "make my code run faster" magic wand. If you want to use async features, you need to spend some time reading the vast number of articles that discuss what async is and isn't in C# and how you use it.

Answer (score 0):

if you want use Async , that structure like this :

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> webservce()
{
return await _yourService.GetAllAsync(); // here you should call Async Methods like .ToListAsync ,...
}
```

Comment: I didn't get this.

Comment: If you want use ~async` , your Method Sginature like ` public async Task<ActionResult> webservce()` , and when you want return data in Method , put `await` after `return`

Comment: please see :  https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/the-.net-4.5-asyncawait-feature-in-promise-and-practice/

Answer (score -6):

All is explained on msdn here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh300224.aspx

Comment: Link only answers are discouraged

Comment: you can add comment no Answer for just link

Comment: Maybe but in this case msdn explains clearly how async await is working. Just giving the solution wouldn't help him for the next time.